# Android Volley custom class request how to pass json string as paramater

Tags: android, android-volley

I create custom request class of volley using android developer site reference, with this i can send parameter as HashMap as follow

```
 Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
 params.put("place","bur");
```

But now i want to pass parameter as json string to server. How can i pass with this?

```
{"place":"bur"}
```

This is my custom request class

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
private final Gson gson = new Gson();
private final Class<T> clazz;
private final Map<String, String> headers;
private final Map<String, String> parms;
private final Listener<T> listener;

public GsonRequest(String url, int method, Class<T> clazz, Map<String,   String> headers,
    Map<String, String> parms, Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);

    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.parms = parms;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    return parms != null ? parms : super.getParams();
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}


@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {

        String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

        Log.i("json", json);

        return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
            HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this HashMap? Anyway: JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject();   myObj.put("place", "bur");

Comment: i dont need hash map, i want to send this parameters as json string with (Custom request class not with JsonObjectRequest)

Comment: Does your custom class extends JsonObjectRequest?

Comment: please check my edited question for class

Comment: And why do you insist to use a custom class?

Comment: i want converted class object from json response

Comment: You can parse the response using Gson.fromJson using JsonObjectRequest as well. If it's not what you mean, please try to explain again.

Comment: can you please give me example to convert jsonobject  response to my class object

Answer (score 0):

I mainly used these two ways to handle JSON responses:

**Using org.json package (JSONObject and JSONArray)**. This way you don't get the object immediately but disassemble the response row by row. For example, I wrote this code to handle Google Distance Matrix response and get the duration text ([response example here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)):

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject row = responseObject.getJSONArray("rows").getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject element = row.getJSONArray("elements").getJSONObject(0);
String status = element.getString("status");
String durationText = element.getJSONObject("duration").getString("text");
```

**Using Gson to parse the response**. Using this module you can get the class directly as you asked. You need to create a class the perfectly fits your response, and handle it like this:

```
ResponseClass responseClass = new Gson().fromJson(response, ResponseClass.class);
```

You can get Gson [here](https://github.com/google/gson). The main point is that you don't need a custom response in order to use it.